# WHERE and AND clause not return values

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I have this PostgreSQL SQL query for selection few values from 4 tables joined by INNER JOIN, and I have problem with returning a value.

```
Select u.id,u.name,u.image,u.created_at as member_from, 
       p.referral, p.note, 
       CASE WHEN count(l.selfy_id)=NULL THEN '0' ELSE count(l.selfy_id) END as likes_total,
       CASE WHEN count(s.id)=NULL THEN '0' ELSE count(s.id) END as selfies_total 
from users as u
inner join profiles  p on p.user_id = u.id
inner join selfies  s on s.user_id = u.id
inner join likes  l on l.selfy_id = s.id
where (u.active = true and s.active = true and u.id= 2 )
group by u.id,u.name,u.image,member_from,p.referral,p.note;
```

If I exclude in `where` block `s.active = true`  I am getting some result but when included its not returns anything.

In tables selfies I have 4 rows with active true and one with active false values.

Solution was `left join on likes` table.

Comment: Obviously, no row has all three values.  I would suggest that you provide sample data (simplified) and desired results.

Comment: Yes,  you are correct,  missing values in likes table, if use left join likes  l on l.selfy_id = s.id then its return values.  Thank you!

Comment: btw you dont need `CASE`  to handle nulls. `COUNT()` doesnt count null so will return 0. Also `count(s.id)=NULL` is wrong, you cant compare with NULL using equal operator. You need to us `IS` like `SomeValue IS NULL` ... but as I already said `COUNT()` never return null

Comment: Ok,  Thank you, I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment and not relevant to the question being asked (which apparently was solved using `left join`).

`COUNT()` never returns `NULL` values.  And a `CASE` expression only returns a single value with a single type.  And, basically all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`, which is treated as FALSE.  Given these facts, can you name three things wrong with this expression?

```
   CASE WHEN count(l.selfy_id)=NULL THEN '0' ELSE count(l.selfy_id) END as likes_total,
```

You can formulate the `SELECT` as:

```
Select u.id, u.name, u.image, u.created_at as member_from, 
       p.referral, p.note, 
       count(l.selfy_id) as likes_total, count(s.id) as selfies_total
```

Now, these are going to return exactly the same values, because `COUNT()` counts non-NULL values and both of the argument to `COUNT()` are used in `JOIN` conditions -- so are never `NULL`.

I speculate that you really intend:

```
Select u.id, u.name, u.image, u.created_at as member_from, 
       p.referral, p.note, 
       count(distinct l.selfy_id) as likes_total,
       count(distinct s.id) as selfies_total
```

although I am not 100% sure those ids are the right ones to be counting.

Comment: You are the man! distinct s.id solved my another problem! Thank you very much!